# How is it possible that I can use LastPass from more than one computer?

Tags: security, cryptography

Tell me if I'm wrong: LastPass can never see my passwords, because they are encrypted with a key that stays in my own computer?

Then how is it possible that I can use my passwords from another computer?

My only guess is that the key is the password I use to login to LastPass, or at least it is generated based on it, so it is related in some way. So when I login to LastPass from another computer, they key same key is created in that computer.

Comment: @GregS How is this not a programming question? It's a question about web security and cryptography

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key is derived from a password you input. They use PBKDF2 with a user defined  number of iterations according to their [website](http://helpdesk.lastpass.com/security-options/password-iterations-pbkdf2/).